# What is the correct form before a noun, species or species' or species's?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, possessives

In an example used for describing [the meaning of the word "biodiversity"  in Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/biodiversity) the phrase "species habitat and biodiversity" is used:

> **the number and types of plants and animals that exist in a particular area or in the world generally, or the problem of protecting this:**
>
> a new National Biological Survey to protect species habitat and biodiversity

My question is, shouldn't "species" be used with possessive s?
This raises another question: what is the correct form of using the word "species" with possessive s in this context?

Comment: I wouldn't think this would be possessive? `species` seems to be broadly describing a type of habitat rather than a particular set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have three options:

1. In this case, the author uses "species" as an [attributive noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) because it describes "habitat" (and perhaps also "biodiversity").
2. If we wanted to precede "habitat and biodiversity" with a plural posessive (indicating that the habitat and biodiversity somehow "belonged" to multiple species), then we would use the plural possessive form of "species":

> a new National Biological Survey to protect species' habitat and biodiversity

3. We could also precede "habitat and biodiversity" with a singular possessive, but in that case "species" would require a determiner, e.g.:

> a new National Biological Survey to protect a species' habitat and biodiversity

(Note that "species's" is not standard.)

All three options are correct.

Answer (score 3):

You would use species’ which is the plural possessive form of species.

You sentence would be:

> a new National Biological Survey to protect **species’** habitat and biodiversity

You could add more clues to the sentence to show you are talking about more than one:

> a new National Biological Survey to protect **multiple species’** habitat and biodiversity